# new WP_Query() - what is the earliest valid hook?

Tags: wp-query, hooks

Specifically, is it valid to run a new `WP_Query()` during the `plugins_loaded` action?

Comment: A custom instance of `WP_Query` can run in almost any scenario on any hook depending on what you need to do. You'll need to add some context here, specially the code and error

Comment: Users are only authenticated later than `plugins_loaded` and is only available on `init` which runs later than `plugins_loaded`

Comment: I appreciate the input Pieter. However interpreting the BP error isn't really the problem, and I realised that it was just confusing the issue, so I have removed everything that doesn't relate to the real question: What is the earliest hook available for a new WP_Query, if plugins_loaded is not valid?

Comment: post types and taxonomies are registered on `init`, I'd guess that you can't reliably do any querying until after that, but maybe core types would work earlier.

Comment: @Milo - Thanks, that does make some sense. Weirdly though, I can successfully both insert and retrieve posts for a custom post type during `plugins_loaded`. Still, after looking at this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155108/can-register-post-type-be-safely-called-before-init I tried dumping `$wp_post_types` and it only had core items. I find this very confusing, but I'm going to continue on the basis that `init` is the earliest completely reliable action to use.

Answer (score 1):

As @Milo pointed out in the comments above, custom post types and taxonomies are registered on `init`, so this would seem to be the earliest hook available that is guaranteed to work for all content.

Comment: As my last comment is hidden below the fold above, I'll just add that in practice it is a bit confusing; I was able to both insert and retrieve custom-post-type posts on the `plugins_loaded` action - `init` just seems safer.

Comment: wp_query has very little to do with CPT registration as it runs on the DB. The results of the query might not be very useful but that depends how you want to use them.

Comment: @MarkKaplun will a tax query succeed if it's not a registered taxonomy returned by `get_taxonomies`? I've noticed that invalid post types or taxonomies result in an impossible SQL condition, are those values not validated against registered types?

Comment: @Milo, not sure how taxonomies work, but wp_query should be a relatively easy query on the posts table and if the post_type in the table is "X" then querying for it should return it even if it is not registered as a post type. How will that impact any code after the query itself I guess depends on what you do with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any hook before `wp_loaded` unless it performs some initialization, or required for user authentication, therefor the earliest is `wp_loaded`

Comment: Never mind - seems I don't read too well!

Answer (score -2):

This is *template_redirect*

Here : https://www.rarst.net/images/wordpress_core_load.png

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'yourFunction');
```

Comment: Can you elaborate _why_ the earliest hook where it is valid to run a `new WP_Query` is this one?

Comment: For the default WP_Query, in the core, it is the first hook after it. You can test an other query type in plugins_loaded.